# Connector's placement - EMC

Tags: pcb, connector, emc

Why placing connectors on the same edge of the PCB is recommended as an EMC design guideline?

As mentioned in https://learnemc.com/pcb-layout

All connectors should be located on one edge or on one corner of a board.
Connectors represent the most efficient antenna parts in most designs. Locating them on the same edge of the board makes it much easier to control the common-mode voltage that may drive one connector relative to another.

Comment: Who said it is?

Comment: Can you provide a source for this? Perhaps the context makes it clear why it would say this.

Comment: [Citation needed]

Comment: Ok I have rechecked and the guideline is: "place all connectors on the SAME edge of the board" as explained here https://learnemc.com/pcb-layout in guideline number 4

Comment: That is your reason.

Comment: I have seen connectors all over boards of all types. Often it is placed at the point of use to avoid long winding traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connectors themselves aren't good antennas, but there is an assumption that long wires will be connected to them.  They may or may not be shielded, but in most cases each conductor is likely longer than your whole PCB.  To protect your circuit from absorbing/radiating through them, it's best to designate an area of the PCB for connectors, clearing out even the ground plane (which might pick up external noise) and filtering each line at the border of the shielded area.  Feedthrough filters are excellent for this purpose.